# How to make any imagebutton a menu button

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, menu, imagebutton

I have an imageButton in a xml file. Now want to make it a menu button, so that when a user click on the button it should show the drop down menus. But I am not able to figure out what are the possible solution(s).
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're trying to show a drop down menu when clicking an **ImageButton** (or any other **View**), try this:

```
final ImageButton imageButton = // get your ImageButton from the XML here

final PopupMenu dropDownMenu = new PopupMenu(getContext(), imageButton);

final Menu menu = dropDownMenu.getMenu();
// add your items:
menu.add(0, 0, 0, "An item");
menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Another item");
// OR inflate your menu from an XML:
dropDownMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.some_menu, menu);

dropDownMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 0:
                // item ID 0 was clicked
                return true;
            case 1:
                // item ID 1 was clicked
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dropDownMenu.show();
    }
});

// if you want to be able to open the menu by dragging on the button:
imageButton.setOnTouchListener(dropDownMenu.getDragToOpenListener());
```

When Android Studio asks to import PopupMenu you may see two options:

1. **android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu** this is the best option, it ensures your menu will work in any Android version
2. **android.widget.PopupMenu** this one only works on Android 2.1 and up, which is probably fine. However, if new Android versions come with new features in **PopupMenu**, the first option may also let you use those new features in older Android versions.

Comment: How to customize the color of this pop up menu?

Comment: @Ashu_1907 I'm not sure this is the best way but try this (example with blue background and green text):
In your themes.xml or styles.xml file add:
`<style name="MenuTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
   <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MenuStyle</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>
<style name="MenuStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
   <item name="android:popupBackground">#0000FF</item>
</style>`
Then replace `new PopupMenu(getContext(), imageButton)` with `new PopupMenu(new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.MenuTheme) imageButton)`

Comment: I have tried the above code but the background color remains same but, the the color of the texts inside the pop up menu changes.